# Copy data to a different server on schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 servers, `Production` and `Repository`, and I need to move data of one table only that is getting new data every day, from production server to repository server on a schedule. And not to insert duplicates into the repository.

Is there a way to create such a job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to do it:

- Create SQL statement to do this task, something like:

  ```
  INSERT INTO [REMOTE_SERVER].[REMOTE_DB].dbo.[TABLE_NAME] 
     SELECT * FROM LOCAL_TABLE
        WHERE LOCAL_TABLE.KEY_FIELD NOT IN 
           (SELECT KEY_FIELD FROM [REMOTE_SERVER].[REMOTE_DB].dbo.[TABLE_NAME])
  ```

  and run this query periodically using JOB
- Use [MS SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)

Comment: how will this query do with performance, if we will have millions of rows.

thank you

Comment: I don't think it will be fast because the tables on the different servers. To improve performance you can store KEY_FIELD from the REMOTE_SERVER on the LOCAL_SERVER and change the query to NOT IN (SELECT KEY_FIELD_ON_REMOTE_SERVER FROM SPECIAL_TABLE), but it will be work only if you put records on REMOTE_SERVER from one LOCAL_SERVER

Answer (score 0):

- [Use Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx)
- [Create Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)

  ```html
  INSERT INTO "ServerName".DBName.dbo.TableName
    SELECT A.* 
      FROM TableName A 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN "ServerName".DBName.dbo.TableName B A.KeyField = B.KeyField
    WHERE B.KeyField IS NULL
  ```